# Flipping or transitioning the current view

Tags: ios, view, transition

I was wondering whether it is possible to transition the `current view` back to itself?

Basically I have a view with many labels on it, and I want to replace all these label values but do not want to change the view- only give the impression the view has changed by transitioning ?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `currentView` with all the labels that is placed on a superview-- `self.view` and 
you have a button on UIView. On Action of that button you want to flip your currentView and change the labels , then you can do something like this:

```
    - (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {
      // change labels on current view
      [UIView transitionWithView:currentView
                        duration:0.8
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      animations:^{


                      }
                      completion:NULL];
      }
    }
```